# Why file names are named so in the web

Tags: database, image, filenames

Why are some file names - esp images - named like 89a1ea695fb3684985b2eb64de97, or some html files named as long numbers instead of it's own name? Is is a concept in databases and file storage? Something about file hierarchy?

Answer (score 2):

Because when server store a lot of images (like facebook). It will be duplicated.

For example, you upload a image which is named "avatar.jpg", and I also upload a image which has the same name. If server don't change its name, my avatar and your avatar will be conflict.

And they use hash function (e.g md5) or other ways to change its name, may be add some salt like date time.

Comment: I understand... So you mean, the images with weird such made using md5 are generally posted by users and the ones seen with normal names should be posted by the creaters - right?

Comment: @cyberfrenzy no, both image names wil be changed to ensure it has unique name.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid file name conflicts, some services save / generate file names using hash (ex. MD5).